# I wanted to make plasma pen. So I made mini ZVS circuit which worked but when I connected it to inductor and transformer it stopped working

Tags: induction, zvs

I had used these components 333 ohm resistors, an led as indicator, 1uF capacitor (50V), NIKOS P75N02LDG MOSFETs,4R7 inductor, PH 4148 diodes, ccfl transformer from laptop backlight inverter board ( easy to fit in pen), 5-9V battery as input. I think my ZVS circuit is properly working as when I used a pair of LEDs to test it, switching works when in connect negative wire to LEDs one after other and my transformer is also fine. One more thing when I connect ZVS driver to transformer then the LED blinks and turns off immediately. So where the problem is?[image]

Comment: No, post your actual schematic with proper values. That is what a schematic is for; it shouldn't rely on disclaimers in text. Do the job properly. Regarding your problem, simulation tools are freely available AND FREE. Try simulating your circuit and finding out why it fails.

Comment: It "works" when it's not drawing much current.What is the source of this schematic? Are you sure of the diodes in the feedback path?

Comment: What does that mean?